# What is the mathematical proof for this Fibonacci fact?

Tags: proof-explanation, fibonacci-numbers

The last digit of the sum of the first *n* Fibonacci numbers is equal to last digit the sum of the last digits of the first *n* Fibonacci numbers.

*i.e.* Assume ***S(n)*** is the sum of the first *n* Fibonacci numbers.

*S(10)* = 0 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 5 + 8 + 1**3** + 2**1** + 3**4** + 5**5** = 143

*S(10)* % 10 = 143 % 10 = 3

The above result is equivalent to 0 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 5 + 8 + **3** + **1**+ **4**+ **5**= 33

If we now take 33 % 10 we get 3 the same result as before

Comment: Sorry, why isn't this true for any collection of numbers?  Only the last digits have any impact on the last digit of the sum.  Or am I misreading?

Comment: There is no "proof" anywhere, and I could substitute any sequence of numbers and any base. It all boils down to modulo.

Comment: Because $13 = 10 + 3$, $21 = 20 + 1$, etc. You've just left out a few multiples of $10$ in your second result, which obviously gives the same result if you take modulo 10.

Comment: Why only the last digits have any impact on the last digit of the sum ?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Look up "casting out nines" e.g. on [Wkipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casting_out_nines) or in [many posts here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+casting)

Comment: Can anyone explain why this was down-voted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not about Fibonacci numbers; rather it is true of any integers at all.
$$
\begin{array}{cccccc}
  & 1 & 4 & 7 \\
+ & 6 & 5 & 6 \\
\hline & \bullet & \bullet & 3
\end{array}
$$
The last digit of the sum is seen to be determined by the last digits of the numbers being added if you look at the algorithm for addition that you were taught in elementary school, i.e. above you see that you have a $7$ and a $6$ as the last digits. You don't need to know what digits come before those in order to know that you'll get a $3$ as the last digit of the sum.

In the language of modular arithmetic, one can say that since $(147\equiv 7) \pmod {10}$ and $(656\equiv 6) \pmod{10},$ you can conclude that $(147+656 \equiv 7+6) \pmod{10}.$

That can be shown by a bit of algebra:
$$
(10a+d) + (10b+ e) = 10(a+b) + (d+e)
$$
where $d,e \in\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}.$